# Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 2898

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I created an MSI installer with WiX 3.8 and I get this kind of errors in the MSI log when installing it:

> MSI (c) (7C:80) [19:14:45:819]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 2898
>   Info 2898.For WixUI_Font_Title textstyle, the system created a 'Tahoma' font, in 0 character set, of 14 pixels height.

How can I fix these errors?
Or maybe they are known WiX/MSI issues that can be safely ignored?

My WiX script is extremely simple, it just installs a shell extension and does not mess with SQL nor fonts, so I have no idea where these errors come from.

The [documentation for error 2898](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372835%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does not give details.

From the GUI point of view, the installation finishes with no visible problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an informational message, which is only output when using the verbose switch of the logging functionality of `msiexec`, i.e. `msiexec /i installer.msi /l*v log.log`.

As you might already know, the msi file generated by your project is a relational database. The line looking like SQL in your log is in fact only stating which message is selected from the [Error Table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368554%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the msi database. Oftentimes, strings stored in the Error Table are not errors but simply informational messages.

This particular message informs you which [TextStyle](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/textstyle.html) is used in the current Dialog. You can set the TextStyle either by specifying the reserved property [DefaultUIFont](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368266%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or by explicitly defining which style to use for each `Control`. This is done by prefixing the name of the style in the text attribute of a control element like so:

```
<TextStyle Id="MyStyle"
  FaceName="Tahoma"
  Size="14"
  Bold="yes" />
<Control Id="styledText"
  Type="Text"
  X="50" Y="50"
  Width="200" Height="20"
  Text="{\MyStyle}A styled message" />
```

Comment: Are you saying this is actually not an error, but just a normal information message that I should not worry about?

Comment: Exactly, nothing to worry about.